# xmodmap no longer works for XF86 keys?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xorg, gentoo, xmodmap

I recently upgraded xorg-server to 1.7.7 on gentoo linux (along with a bunch of other upgrades...). It seems that xmodmap no longer accepts my .Xmodmap file. I get errors like

```
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:82:  bad keysym name 'XF86Sleep' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:83:  bad keysym name 'XF86WakeUp' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:85:  bad keysym name 'XF86Favorites' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:87:  bad keysym name 'XF86Stop' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:88:  bad keysym name 'XF86HomePage' in keysym list
[snip]
```

I poked around and found the `/usr/include/X11/XF86keysym.h` file, which now has things like `XF86XK_Foo` in it, so I changed my .Xmodmap, and now I get errors like this:

```
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:82:  bad keysym name 'XF86XK_Sleep' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:83:  bad keysym name 'XF86XK_WakeUp' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:85:  bad keysym name 'XF86XK_Favorites' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:87:  bad keysym name 'XF86XK_Stop' in keysym list
/usr/bin/xmodmap:  /home/oz/.Xmodmap:88:  bad keysym name 'XF86XK_HomePage' in keysym list
[snip]
```

Where did my XF86 keys go? do I need to change a flag for xorg-server? This is under xmodmap-1.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

XF86keysym.h has always had the names with XF86XK_* in - the #defines used in C code
are different than the keysym names used by xmodmap.

If you're using libX11 1.3.5 or older, you should be getting the keysym names from a file
such as `/usr/share/X11/XKeysymDB` (in libX11 1.4 those move into the libX11 builtin table).